# How to set playbackRates in JWPlayer Android SDK

Tags: android, jwplayer

I'm used JWPlayer for play video in native android, I want to set playbackRates for up/down video speed, but I didn't find a way to use it, Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue and contacted JWPlayer. They report that this feature will be released by August 2018.